# Likelihood of errors based on a sample

Tags: probability

I frequently do something like: load a bunch of data, and then scan some fraction of it randomly to verify that no errors occurred. The more data I verify, the greater my certainty that no errors occurred anywhere.

I'm curious about how I can express this formally. My thought process is:

Suppose there are $n$ records, of which $k$ contain errors. The probability of a randomly selected one containing an error is $k/n$ and conversely, the probability of selecting one without an error is $1-k/n$. If I model this as a Bernoulli process, I believe the probability of $t$ samples all having no error is $\left(1-k/n\right)^t$. So given some information about the data, I can get the probability of finding no errors.

But what I really want is the reverse: given that I found no errors, what confidence do I have that there are less than $k_{act}$ errors in actuality? I think I could use Bayes' theorem here, but that would require me having some priors which seem difficult to estimate.

Can I just set my formula equal to, say, $.95$ and solve, and then claim I've found a 95% confidence interval?

By the way, I'm interested for curiosity's sake. I think a more realistic attempt would take into account that errors would tend to propagate, for example.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/sample-size-to-determine-if-success-proportion-is-zero)?

Comment: See the (oddly-named) Wikipedia article [Rule of three (medicine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28medicine%29)

Comment: Incidentally, your title is confusing in that (a) it uses likelihood in the common, not the statistical, meaning of the terms and (b) it uses errors in the sense of defects or negatives, rather than random errors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is called [Laplace's succession rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession), namely that if you have seen no error in a batch of $t$ independent draws from a Bernoulli $B(p)$, the (posterior) probability that the next draw will error-free is
$$
\dfrac{t+1}{t+2}\,.
$$
This is Bayesian in that you put a uniform prior on the probability of error, $p$. No need to "estimate" anything.

The way you presented the problem is slightly different in that you are working on an hypergeometric assumption, hence the probability of having $t$ draws with no error is
$$
\dfrac{{t \choose n-k}\times 1}{{t \choose n}}
$$
rather than the $(1=\frac{k}{n})^t$ you proposed. If $n$ is large compared with $t$, it does not make too much of a difference. Otherwise, if you put a uniform prior on $k$, you recover once again Laplace's rule,
$$
P(k=0|X_t=0) = \dfrac{t+1}{t+2}\,.
$$
(This is detailed in Section 4.3.1 on [*The Bayesian Choice*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387715983). The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession) is unnecessarily convoluted.)